# What's the difference between client-side and server-side authentication?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

There is passport for Node.js but Sattelizer for AngularJS. I am having trouble understanding when to use which one.

What does Sattelizer do that passport doesn't do and vice versa? What does JSON Web Tokens do in terms of authentication?

Answer (score 0):

***Satellizer*** works on the client side to call the server side api's proper REST routes for anthentication and handles the sending/receiving of tokens.

On the server-side, ***Passport*** can receive and send those tokens, and do password validation on the database, for example...

But you don't need Passport to work with Satellizer: Check the Server-side example here:
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server/node

Answer (score 0):

Satellizer will hep you store and use the session on the client side that is in the browser you can do an inspect element on the demo link on my repo https://github.com/Leo-G/Flask-Scaffold, in local storage you sell see the JSON token, This token was generated on the server and passed to the client on authentication. The below article explains in detail how this is done

http://techarena51.com/index.php/json-web-token-authentication-with-flask-and-angularjs/